# Using regular expressions on google analytics goal funnels?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, goal-tracking

I want to create a goal funnel on Google by using regualar expressions:

for example lets say the website is `www.example.com`

and the funnel journey should be

```
1. Category Page    i.e. /brands/nike
2. Product Page     i.e. /brands/nike/nike-air-trainers
3. Checkout         i.e /checkout/onepage/success/
```

How can u write in this regular expression, the reason Im asking this is how will google differentiate between the category page and a product page?

Answer (score 1):

```
1. Category Page i.e. /brands/nike - regex: /brands/[^/]+
2. Product Page  i.e. /brands/nike/nike-air-trainers - regex: /brands/[^/]+/(.+)
3. Checkout      i.e. /checkout/onepage/success/ - regex: /success/ or /checkout/[^/]*/success/
```